# Android GPS nmea settings

Tags: android, gps

I need to get real GPS time from GPS module on Android device. My app realizes nmeaListener and i receive some raw NMEA packets with onNmeaReceived() callback. Threre is one string in NMEA protocol, that contains data and time - $GPZDA. But my callback doesn't give it ti me. There are all other string except this one.

Is there some way to ask GPS module bring it to mee with Android SDK tools? Or any other ways?

Comment: `Threre is one string in NMEA protocol, that contains data and time - $GPZDA. `. Are you sure? I think there are several others.

Comment: Yeap - several other contains only time, but not date

Comment: Please name them all that you receive. What kind of GPS module do you use? I suppose you use an external one.

Comment: For instance GPRMC does contain date and time.

Comment: That's what i've got from onNmeaReceived callback:

NMEA MESSAGE:  $GPRMC,075239.00,A,5538.533544,N,03728.327837,E,0.0,0.0,171215,8.8,W,A*23
NMEA MESSAGE:  $GPGGA,075239.00,5538.533544,N,03728.327837,E,1,06,2.1,211.4,M,15.5,M,,,*47
NMEA MESSAGE:  $GPGSV,4,1,14,01,16,291,17,04,42,287,,08,54,254,19,10,67,079,12*73 NMEA MESSAGE:  $GPGSV,4,2,14,11,29,295,27,14,42,146,13,15,03,033,,18,34,073,*75
 NMEA MESSAGE:  $GPGSV,4,3,14,21,10,116,,22,78,108,,24,15,059,,27,44,202,22*72

Comment: As you can see - the first item of GPRMC string contains 6 digits - that corresponds to hhmmss pattern. It's time. But i also need a date, that can be found only in GPZDA string - but this string is absent((

Comment: You overlooked the date. $GPRMC,075239.00,A,5538.533544,N,03728.327837,E,0.0,0.0,`171215`,8.8,W,A*23 That is 17-12-2015. Today ;-)

Comment: @ЕвгенийКравцов I have a similar issue, maybe you have an idea how to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63917764/gpgga-and-gprmc-sentences-are-not-received-in-onnmeamessage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overlooked the date. $GPRMC,075239.00,A,5538.533544,N,03728.327837,E,0.0,0.0,`171215`,8.8,W,A*23

171215 is 17-12-2015.

Today ;-)

Comment: Wow, that's it))) How can i be so lame) Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @greenapps I have a similar problem, maybe you can help me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63917764/gpgga-and-gprmc-sentences-are-not-received-in-onnmeamessage